# Kivy save widget without being drawn results in blank Fbo

Tags: kivy

I am trying to render some labels over the top of a canvas texture i have previously saved. When i render the widget to an Fbo without drawing it to the screen first i get a blank output. I believe this is replicated in the snippet below, save_file called from on_start writes the file incorrectly, but if the same logic is called from the button press it saves a file of the widget rendered correctly.

Is there a way to render the widget to the Fbo without rendering to the canvas?

Is there an update or draw command i need to call on the widget?
(notshown.texture seems to be None, and adding notshown.canvas.draw() seems to crash with no stacktrace or reason?)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.factory import Factory

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self, *kwargs):
        layout = Factory.BoxLayout()
        test1 = Factory.Button(text='test1', size_hint=(None,None), size=(200,200))
        test1.bind(on_press=self.save_file1)
        layout.add_widget(test1)
        test2 = Factory.Button(text='test2', size_hint=(None,None), size=(200,200))
        test2.bind(on_press=self.save_file2)
        layout.add_widget(test2)
        return layout
    def save_file1(self, widget, value=False):
        fbo = Factory.Fbo(size=widget.size, with_stencilbuffer=True)
        fbo.add(widget.canvas)
        fbo.draw()
        fbo.texture.save('C:/Temp/test1.png', flipped=True)
    def save_file2(self, widget, value=False):
        notshown = Factory.Button(text='notshown', size_hint=(None,None), size=(200,200))
        fbo = Factory.Fbo(size=notshown.size, with_stencilbuffer=True)
        fbo.add(notshown.canvas)
        fbo.draw()
        fbo.texture.save('C:/Temp/test2.png', flipped=True)

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App), The `on_start` event is `Fired when the application is being started (before the runTouchApp() call.` So that is probably too soon. Try calling `save_file` with a `Clock.schedule_once()` in the `build()` method.

Comment: I have revised the example to show it occurs fully at runtime, when attempting to render a newly created button to the Fbo

Comment: Keep in mind that kivy is event-based. So anytime you do anything that affects the display, an event is dispatched to trigger an update. But the GUI thread (main thread) cannot respond to that event until your code (also running on the main thread) finishes. That is why the `Clock.schedule_once()` is so useful in scheduling your code to run after allowing the main thread to respond to awaiting events. So, again, calling your `fbo.texture.save()` via  a `Clock.schedule_once()` will probably work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per John Anderson's input, the issue was not giving the application enough time to render a frame before attempting to save the texture.

Using Clock.schedule_once to await the next frame means that export_to_png or all other uses of the texture of the widget succeed with little to no fuss.

```
img = Factory.FinalImage(imagedata, size_hint=(None,None), size=imagedata.size)
Clock.schedule_once( lambda x: img.export_to_png(filename=imagename) )
```